# What's the keyboard layout like?

Tags: bit-trip-core

Bit Trip Core is finally on Steam. While the previous Windows ports of Bit Trip titles were quality ones, I'm a little concerned by this one — maybe I'm a little scarred by Half Minute Hero, but still the nature of the game kind of concerns me. That, and [this comment on the store page](http://store.steampowered.com//app/205060):

> CORE is the second installment in CommanderVideo's soul quest with:
>
> - Classic NES-Style Controls!

If I understand correctly, the core gameplay is pushing a directional key to set the direction of the lazer, then mashing a button in order to fire the lazer with the beat.

What are these buttons on a keyboard?

Comment: You're missing one other part of gameplay which is the Bomb button. I'm assuming "classic NES-Style controls" refers to the fact that all you need to play in the game's other iterations is the D-pad and 2 buttons, analogous to the NES gamepad.

Comment: @fae that's Why I added "Core" :)